# Issues with LINQ and Clipboard security

Tags: c#, silverlight, linq, clipboard

Why do I need to call the ToList() method on my LINQ query?

For example:

```
private void btnEnc_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SHA1 sha = new SHA1Managed();
    string sResult = "";

    var v = sha.ComputeHash(
        UTF8Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(tbxWordToEncrypt.Text)
        ).Select(
            p => sResult += string.Format("{0:x2}", p)
        ).ToList();

    Clipboard.SetText(sResult);

    tbxEncrypted.Text = sResult;
}
```

Also, when I try to access the clipboard I get a security dialog box. How can I prevent this?

[image: SilverLight ClipBoard Access MessageBox]

Comment: These are two entirely separate questions.  The SO community would be better served if they were posted in two different questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason that you need to call to list is because the expression inside the Select isn't evaluated until the expression created by the LINQ statement is evaluated.  Because you're using it to append to `sResult`, that variable won't have had its value changed before you put it on the clipboard unless you "run" the LINQ expression using ToList().  Note that the output of ToList() is basically worthless.

The bigger problem is that you're misusing the Select.  You really should be using string.Join instead of building the string inside the Select clause.  Building it inside the Select clause is going to be unexpected for people reading your code and harder to understand.

```
var sResult = string.Join( "",
                 sha.ComputeHash(
                       UTF8Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(tbxWordToEncrypt.Text)
                 ).Select(
                       p => string.Format("{0:x2}", p)
                 ));
```

Comment: Thank you so much. How can I think like you? Is there any book/s to develop my perspective...?

Comment: @uzay95 - I can't point to one book, but I do focus on learning and improving. Code Complete is a very good book for every software dev if you haven't already read that but it's not enough. I read a bunch of blogs - Robert Martin, Phil Haack, Scott Guthrie.  I spend a fair amount of time answering questions on SO - which often forces me to learn more about the technologies in question. You might want to try answering more questions or, more to the point, find a question related to something you're doing that you don't know the answer to and start doing research until you can answer it.

Answer (score 5):

By default you run under partial trust. When calling ClipBoard.SetText() (or ClipBoard.SetText(...)) the user must confirm access.

If you create an out-of-browser application and request elevated trust, this restriction no longer applies and no dialog box is shown.

You can configure your application to require elevated trust. You need to set this in the application's manifest.

For more information take a look at MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721083(v=vs.95).aspx

1. Open your project's properties and navigate to the Silverlight tab.
2. Check the option "Enable running application out of browser".
3. Click on the button Out-Of-Browser Settings. A new dialog will popup.
4. Check the option "Require elevated trust when running outside the browser".

When a user installs your Silverlight application they will get a security warning before they can proceed. This only happens once. When running your application this way the ClipBoard.SetText() call will no longer trigger a security dialog.

Answer (score 0):

As for Linq:

You only need to call `ToList()` if you want the data to be evaluated imediatly.

Most Linq operators are [lazy](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2006/10/04/lazy-evaluation-_2800_and-in-contrast_2c00_-eager-evaluation_2900_.aspx) by design, and it's a good thing.